# Ruby on Rails 5: redirect_to giving url and path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a rails 5 web app. Everything is working great on my localhost development environment.  I have a Digital Ocean dropplet (running Ubuntu 14.04, nginx/puma, and mySql).  As per the normal sequence, after one logs in, I redirect to the root_path.  Again on my localhost environment, this works as expected, but on the remote host (still under development environment) the redirect_to function gives both the url and the path.

here is my login controller code:

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def login
    user = User.find_by_uname params[:uname]
    if user.present?
      @user = user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if @user.present?
        puts "@user present"
        session[:userid] = @user.id
        session[:uname] = @user.uname
        @modal = 'login'
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        puts "@user did not authenticate -- wrong password"
      end
    else
      puts "#{params[:uname]} not in database."
      render partial: 'utility/loginfailure', as: :js
    end
  end
end
```

in the log/development.log file I see this:

> Redirected to http://ruby.morgotha.net, ruby.morgotha.net/

From that it would seem to be coming from the redirect method, but it works fine on localhost dev.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this anymore. So if someone is willing to guide me on digging into this a bit deeper, I sure would appreciate it.

**Edit** I changed the session controller to not need the return statement. The problem is still happening.  root_path resolves to just "/".

Comment: I guess in your `apache`/`nginx` you configured the project root with this url `ruby.morgotha.net`. Thus, it is serving as root path. And, if you redirect, then there shouldn't be any `return` statement.

Comment: as I was posting this question, I did consider the return statement after the redirect. I took it out, and tried again.  It errored saying that I had multiple renderings.  But maybe your right.  I will see if I can re-write the controller such that a return will not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ends up being a mis-configured Nginx configuration. 
this is what I had for my root location

```
  location / {
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 768;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;  <---- this line is the problem
    proxy_pass http://grah;
  }
```

and the line with 'proxy_redirect off;' is the problem. removing that line, redirect_to now work as expected.